# File upload with json payload netty

Tags: java, json, file-upload, netty, multipartform-data

I'm using netty 4 to multi-part file upload but don't know how to send the jsaon body along with the upload file (.jpg/.pdf/.etc.)

Could you please help me to achieve this functionality using netty 4 and Java.?
Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: UID uniqueFileId = new UID(); FileUpload fileUpload = (FileUpload) data; String fileName =fileUpload.getFilename(); String filePath =fileUpload.getFilename(); String name =fileUpload.getFilename(); try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fileUploadPath + fileName)) { out.write(fileUpload.get());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that JSON doesn't support file upload too well so you first need to decide how you want to encode the file & meta data.

You basically have four choices:

1. Use form encoding to send your file instead of json. This has much better file upload support.
2. Base64 encode the file in the json. This will increase filesize by about 33%.
3. Send the file first in a multipart/form-data POST and use the return value to specify an id to send with the json data is a different request
4. Send the json data first and return a url to upload the file to.

I would recommend against using option 2 since it also requires manipulating the file in memory. Using multipart/form-data will let netty save the file to the file system if it is large so you don't have to store it in memory.

Comment: Thanks the option 3 worked fine. Thanks for your help!